# Virtual serial port driver 7.1, hyperterminal and nokia

Tags: hyperterminal

I need to connect my Nokia phone to my PC via hyper terminal
i've downloaded virtual serial port driver 7.1 and installed it since i do not have a serial port in my pc

When i use hyperterminal, the com port created with the driver appears, but when i use them i can't get no response ? from the phone

Thanks